# org.mockito.internal.stubbing.ConsecutiveStubbin

Tags: eclipse, junit, mockito, stubbing

I'm new with Mockito/Junit and I've been tasked with implementing some testing into some old code.  I've created a test class but am receiving the consecutiveStubbing error and I cant seem to figure it out.  I'm hoping someone can explain the error to me.

Tried searching the web but results for the error are lacking (except for the Mockito documentation).

This is the test

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing;

import cbsa.enrolment.entities.Trgc202Evnt;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EventDisplayTest {
    
//  @InjectMocks
//  Trgc202Evnt trgEvnt;
    
    @Mock
    EventDisplay evntDsp;
    
    //String rslt;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetDescription() {
        Trgc202Evnt trgEvnt = new Trgc202Evnt();
        evntDsp = mock(EventDisplay.class);
        Short docType = (short) 3;  //Type Document
        trgEvnt.setEvntEntyTcsn(docType);  // set the docType before all
        String expectedRslts1 = "Drivers Licence Document Captured"; // expected text returned
        
        OngoingStubbing<String> rslt = when(evntDsp.getDescription(trgEvnt)).thenReturn("Drivers Licence Document Captured");

        Assert.assertEquals("### EvenDisplay getDescription(document type) failed. ###", expectedRslts1, rslt);
// This Line causing the error, I think because *rslt* is stubbed but if I change it to a String then Mockito error says it must be converted to OngoingStubbing

    }
} 


this is the stack trace



 java.lang.AssertionError: ### EvenDisplay getDescription(document type) failed. ### expected:<Drivers Licence Document Captured> but was:<org.mockito.internal.stubbing.ConsecutiveStubbing@c054e24>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at cbsa.enrolment.web.display.EventDisplayTest.testGetDescription(EventDisplayTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Please format the stack trace as code snippets to prevent line breaks. Otherwise it's hard to read. The code is not compileable because of the `>` at the beginning of the lines and because `cbsa.enrolment.entities.Trgc202Evnt` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the test to work but I'm not convinced its the proper way of doing it.

I changed the test function to the following after I declared some variables in the setup()

@Test
public void testGetDescription() {

```
String expectedRslts1 = "Drivers Licence Document Captured"; // expected text returned

when(evntDsp.getDescription(trgEvnt)).thenReturn("Drivers Licence Document Captured");
Assert.assertEquals("### EvenDisplay getDescription(document type) failed. ###", expectedRslts1, evntDsp.getDescription(trgEvnt));
```

}

Is this a valid test of the getDescription() method?